# Dataset of User Transaction history

Tags: data-request

I am looking for User Transaction Dataset for movies
I have recently come across Movielens Dataset. http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/
This dataset consists ratings of the movies given by users. But I need a dataset that contains user transaction histories
Like User 1 purchased movie X Y in first transaction, C,D,X in another transaction and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo! News Feed User Dataset consists data of users pulled across various Yahoo! properties, including Yahoo! Movies; its made up "of user-news item interaction data, collected by recording the user- news item interaction of about 20M users from February 2015 to May 2015."
I'm not sure if this has exactly the transaction data you want, but it is worth looking into:
http://webscope.sandbox.yahoo.com/catalog.php?datatype=r&did=75